# How to solve Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, android-studio, dart

I'm new to programming using flutter and I ran into an error that I can't manage to fix.
I have installed both dart and flutter and downloaded all plugins whatsoever on both android studio and visual studio.
I then created the first project with flutter and I opened it with android studio, I didn't change anything and I immediately tried to start the application to see if it worked or not, but it gives me this error that I can't solve.

```
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Canvas, Paint, Path;
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:ui' is imported through these packages:

    package:prova => package:flutter => dart:ui
    ...

Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:

    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    package:prova/main.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    ...

/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/badge_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/banner_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^

Process finished with exit code 254
```

Online I found a lot of people with a similar problem that they solved adding the path to flutter and dart in the android studio's settings, but I have already insert them and nothing seems to change.

My only thought is that i installed flutter in a folder different to the default one, maybe I need to make some additions to the environment variables?

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates that Dart Libraries which are needed by Flutter are not available on your system.
Sometimes you get this error because may be you are using unsupported platform or if the configuration is gone wrong.

Try the following steps

i) Make sure you have set up your environment variables correctly.

ii) Make sure that the 'flutter/bin' directory is added to your system's PATH variable.

iii) Check if you have the required dependencies installed.

iv) Make sure Dart sdk and android sdk are installed properly.

v) Flutter projects are typically developed using IDEs/editors like Visual Studio Code or Android Studio. Make sure you have a compatible editor installed and that you're opening the project within that editor.

vi)If you have updated flutter  try running the following command in your project directory to fetch the latest Flutter dependencies:
"flutter packages get"

vii) Check your pubspec.yaml file for missing dependencies.